# Create a matrix for datapoints in same or different clusters

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want to iterate through my datapoints and check whether they are in the same cluster, after using KMeans to cluster them.
And then I need to create a matrix for all the datapoints, and have 1 if they belong on the same cluster, and 0 if they don't.
After using Kmeans, I'm not sure how to retrieve which cluster every datapoint belongs to so I can create such matrix.
Do I do that using labels_ argument?

```
  k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(X)

  labels_columns = k_means.labels_

  labels_row = k_means.labels_

  for row in labels_row:
      for column in labels_columns:
           if row == columns:
              --add 1 in matrix position
           else:
               --add 0 in matrix position
```

How to best create this matrix? Or do they labels_ provide different information from what my understanding?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. `Kmeans.labels_` returns a vector of `n` elements which tells you that the 
cluster each point belongs to: `[3, 4, 10, ...]` tells you that point `0` belongs to cluster `3`, point `1`
 belongs to cluster `4` and so on.

You can build the matrix you want in many ways. One possibility I thought which is a bit more elegant than
 2 `for` loops would be the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

n_samples, n_features = 10, 2
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples, n_features)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.show()

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=kmeans.labels_)
plt.show()

neighbour_matrix = np.zeros(n_samples)
repeat_labels = np.repeat(kmeans.labels_.T, n_samples, axis=0).reshape(n_samples, n_samples)
print(kmeans.labels_)
print(repeat_labels)
proximity_matrix = (repeat_labels == repeat_labels.T).astype(int)
print(proximity_matrix)
```

I use the vector of labels as my starting point. Let's say that it is the following:
`[1 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 0]`
I transform it in a 2D matrix with `np.repeat` which has the following shape:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
.....
```

So I repeat the labels as many times as is the number of points `n`. Then I can just check where this 
 matrix and its transpose are equal. That will be true only if two points belong to the same cluster:

```
[[1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
.....
```

I casted the matrix to `int`, but mind you that the original output is actually a boolean array.

I left the `print` statements and the plots in the code to hopefully make it more clear.
Hope it helps!